# what is wrong with my pdo syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to execute a pdo update statement definded as follows:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE users SET (email,name) VALUES (:email,:name) WHERE userId = :userId";
 $result= $db->prepare($sql);
 $result->execute(array(':userId'=>21,':email'=>'test',':name'=>'testname'));
```

But no matter what I try it returns the following error

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(email,name) VALUES ('test','testname') WHERE userId = '21'' at line 1' in /var/www/vhosts/tftest.co.uk/biggreensquare.co.uk/application/models/user_model.php:79
```

I can't see what is wrong with my syntax that is causing this any feedback much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect the syntax to look like:

```
UPDATE users
    SET email = :email,
        name = :name
    WHERE userId = :userId;
```